# Delphi: playing mp3 in 64-bit exe

Tags: delphi, mp3, win64

Targeting Windows7+ systems, what's a simple way to play MP3s from my Delphi (10.2 Tokyo) app compiled in 64-bit? I had been using DSPack with 32-bit, but in 64-bit it won't compile. Had a look at BASS but it's also not working on 64-bit.

Preferably something working directly with the Windows API would be preferable over including external dlls with the app.

Comment: There are many libraries that can do this, certainly including BASS. Did you give up too soon on it? You can certainly do this using the built in libraries, DirectShow for instance. Even good old `mciSendString`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way is to use [`mciSendString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757161.aspx).

```
uses
  Winapi.MMSystem;
....
mciSendString('open audiofile.mp3 type mpegvideo alias song1', nil, 0, 0);
mciSendString('play song1', nil, 0, 0);
```

Comment: A bit messy but it does the job, made a little wrapper to run in a thread with "wait" and an extra call to close it when finished. Thanks. (mciSendString('play song1 wait', .. mciSendString('close song1'.. )